# version 1.5.1.0 image do not display on back end also directory folders disappears after creation

Tags: image

I am trying to add images under the cms/pages/homepage for magento version 1.5.1.0 However, when I click on content-->show/hide editor / followed by insert image -> create directory and then hit refresh the directory disappears from the list. Furthermore, the images will not upload on the front end or on the backend when I cilck on show/hide editor, after hitting insert?

If any one has an ideas that would be great?

Thanks for your time,

Teli

Comment: You should add a 'Magento' Tag to this Question

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem. You can find the solution here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/220720/P15/#t349314

- Open the file:
  app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
- Around line 62 comment out

FROM

```
$subDirectories = Mage::getModel('core/file_storage_directory_database')->getSubdirectories($path);
        foreach ($subDirectories as $directory) {
            $fullPath = rtrim($path, DS) . DS . $directory['name'];
            if (!file_exists($fullPath)) {
                mkdir($fullPath, 0777, true);
            }
        }
```

to:

```
/* $subDirectories = Mage::getModel('core/file_storage_directory_database')->getSubdirectories($path);
        foreach ($subDirectories as $directory) {
            $fullPath = rtrim($path, DS) . DS . $directory['name'];
            if (!file_exists($fullPath)) {
                mkdir($fullPath, 0777, true);
            }
        }*/
```

Note: To make it in the better way without edit the core of Magento, create the same file and folder structure under the local folder, so the new file with the modification must go to `app/code/local/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php`